# error: type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.Column required: Int

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

In Databricks, I am getting the following error:

> `type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.Column  required: Int`

Please let me know where am I doing a mistake:

```
val getnearestFiveMinSlot =  (next_slot:Int) => {
  val value = spark.sql(f"""
select * from(
  select cast(SLOT as int) from(
SELECT 300  AS SLOT  UNION ALL
SELECT 600    UNION ALL
SELECT 900    UNION ALL
SELECT 1200   UNION ALL
SELECT 1500   UNION ALL
SELECT 1800   UNION ALL
SELECT 2100   UNION ALL
SELECT 2400   UNION ALL
SELECT 2700   UNION ALL
SELECT 3000   UNION ALL
SELECT 3300   UNION ALL
SELECT 3600    
  )
  )
where SLOT >= ${next_slot}
limit 1
 """)
  value.collect()(0)(0).toString().toInt
  }

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val slotValue = List(100,100,100,4,5)
val df = slotValue.toDF("slotValue")
display(df)

val ff = df.withColumn("value_new",(getnearestFiveMinSlot(col("slotValue"))))
display(ff)
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like your `getnearestFiveMinSlot` should be a UDF, isn't it?

Comment: Also not sure why using a SQL query to compute something that can be done in plain Scala code and is static?

Comment: Yes @Gaël J, `getnearestFiveMinSlot ` should be a UDF. I agree, we can do it in plain Scala also, but using SQL.
it's Static

Comment: Then It's missing the `udf { ... }` part.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by **Gaël J**, the error is because of the missing `udf()` part.

- When I used the same code as yours, it gave the same error saying that `error: type mismatch; found: org.apache.spark.sql.Column   required: Int`.

[image]

- The error occurs because we are trying pass `column` as an argument to a normal function (**expecting an Integer argument**).
- We first need to convert this function to a user defined function using `udf()` function. This allows us to pass a column to the `getnearestFiveMinSlot` function. Modify the code to convert `getnearestFiveMinSlot` to UDF and use it as required.

```
val getnearestFiveMinSlot =  (next_slot:Int) => {
  val value = spark.sql(f"""
select * from(
  select cast(SLOT as int) from(
SELECT 300  AS SLOT  UNION ALL
SELECT 600    UNION ALL
SELECT 900    UNION ALL
SELECT 1200   UNION ALL
SELECT 1500   UNION ALL
SELECT 1800   UNION ALL
SELECT 2100   UNION ALL
SELECT 2400   UNION ALL
SELECT 2700   UNION ALL
SELECT 3000   UNION ALL
SELECT 3300   UNION ALL
SELECT 3600    
  )
  )
where SLOT >= ${next_slot}
limit 1
 """)
  value.collect()(0)(0).toString().toInt
  }


import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val slotValue = List(100,100,100,4,5)
val df = slotValue.toDF("slotValue")
display(df)

val getSlot = udf(getnearestFiveMinSlot)

val ff = df.withColumn("value_new",(getSlot(col("slotValue"))))
display(ff)
```

[image]